# how to print 60 degree rotated watermark in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page of A4 size. I use CSS to make it A4 size. Now i want to print watermark on that page in 60 degree. But i could not found any solution. I search many time on google but failed. can anyone please help me?

Here is CSS of that page

```
 <style>
 body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    font: 12pt "Times New Roman";
    }
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .page {
        width: 210mm;
        min-height: 297mm;
        padding: 08mm;
        margin: 2mm auto;
        border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

    }
    .subpage {
        padding: 1cm;
        border: 5px solid;
        height: 257mm;
        outline: 2cm #FFEAEA solid;
    }

    @page {
        size: A4;
        margin: 0 0em 0em 0em;
    }
    @media print {
        html, body {
            width: 210mm;
            height: 297mm;  
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact    
        }
        .page {
            margin: 0;
            border: initial;
            border-radius: initial;
            width: initial;
            min-height: initial;
            box-shadow: initial;
            background: initial;
            page-break-after: always;
        }
        </style>
```

Comment: have you tried setting your watermark image as background of the page?

Comment: I want to print Text Watermark

Comment: what is the purpose of watermark using css? user may simply remove the watermark before printing.

Comment: this file use in internal office. And need to watermark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use opacity and position fixed.

```
.for-watermark-div
{
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 257px;
 right: 100px;
 opacity: 0.5;
 z-index: 99;
 color: hotpink;
 /* Rotate div */
 -ms-transform: rotate(60deg); /* IE 9 */
 -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 transform: rotate(60deg);
 pointer-events: none; /*edited: this will prevent ignoring background links*/
}
```

Comment: it print watermark in bottom and angle was 90 but i want to print it in middle of page and want angle of 60 degree